# How can I get QLineSeries name of graph when mouse horvers in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt6

In this picture name of blue line is Week 1 but it displayed as Week 2.
[image]

This is my python code.(I used pyqt6.)

```
for ls_Series in li_Points:
    self.ob_Chart_Viewer.chart.addSeries(ls_Series)
    name = ls_Series.name()
    ls_Series.hovered.connect(lambda point: QToolTip.showText(QCursor.pos(), "%s\nx:%.2f\ny: %.2f" % (name, point.x(), point.y())))
    ls_Series.clicked.connect(ls_Series.hide)
    ls_Series.attachAxis(self.ob_Chart_Viewer.axis_x)
    ls_Series.attachAxis(self.ob_Chart_Viewer.axis_y)
```

How can I get correct name?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
ls_Series.hovered.connect(
    lambda point, series=ls_Series: QToolTip.showText(
        QCursor.pos(), "%s\nx:%.2f\ny: %.2f" % (series.name(), point.x(), point.y())
    )
)
```

Comment: @bituniverse are you sure? Could you provide an MRE so I can test it.

Comment: @bituniverse Ooops, MRE: [mre]

Comment: I found solution.
Your code occures error.
My solution is to use sender() function.